# How can I hide a windows drive?

Tags: wubi, windows-7, hard-drive

I have a partition with system files, boots etc. (I have Lenovo G570, and it came with this partition. It is 200 mb partition, without a letter). On the window OS, it hides all this drive, so I cannot see it. I don't want to see it when I use Ubuntu OS, how can I make it disappear?
P.S. I use WUBI

Comment: The system drive is a windows system drive. Windows uses it to boot and... stuff. About hiding it(at the top of my head) you can hide it using gparted>right click on the partition and select>hide. Warning i newer tried this on the windows system drive.

Answer (score 1):

To hide a Partition:

1. Install [Gparted](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gparted)(if you already don't have it installed).
2. Right click on the partition you want to set as hidden.(You may recognize the partition by it's size and File System).

[image: Gparted]
 3. Select Manage Flags and check the flag *hidden*.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from /etc/fstab to prevent auto-mounting. 
First, see if it is there. You could recognize it from the name, mount point, or comment before it:

```
  less /etc/fstab
```

Then comment out the line that defines the drive, for example, by adding **#** at the beginning of the line. Then reboot.

```
  sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

**WARNING**: be very careful not to comment out some other useful drive, such as the root partition "# / was on /dev/sda1..."

Answer (score 0):

To hide a partition from Nautilus without using the hidden flag and possibly breaking your Windows install or preventing Windows from seeing it you can do the following:

1.) `sudo fdisk -l`
Output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      409599      203776    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          409600   208027647   103809024    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

2.) Create a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` say "99-hide-lenovo-data.rules"
3.) Figure out which `/dev/sd[X][N]` the Lenovo data partition is.
4.) Add a rule in 99-hide-lenovo-data.rules like so:

```
KERNEL==”sda1″, ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}=”1″
```